# Double Bitlocker Recovery Tab in Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, bitlocker

I've strange issue with double bitlocker tab having exactly same look. Any idea how I can remove one?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Witnessed on several domains that have gone through upgrades from 2008 to 2012.

The fix outlined below will remove the duplicate **BitLocker Recovery** tab in ADUC and the duplicate **Action > Find BitLocker recovery password** *Action* menu option when running ADUC in an English locale only. For other language locales, the process is the same but a different path is used.

**Remove *Duplicate* BitLocker Recovery Tab**

1. Open ADSI Edit, right-click on ADSI Edit top level node, click Connect to...
2. Select a well known Naming Context: ***Configuration***, click OK. *Do not select the Default Naming Context (which is Domain), we want Configuration.*
3. Drill down to **Configuration** > **DisplaySpecifiers** > **409** and open up the **computer-Display** container.

   - *Substitute 409 for other hex code for other (than English) locales.*
4. In the *Attribute Editor* tab, open **adminPropertyPages**, select **14,{2FB1B669-59EA-4F64-B728-05309F2C11C8}**, and click Remove.

   - Note that two {2FB1B669-59EA-4F64-B728-05309F2C11C8} entries exist in this attribute. We are removing one of them. In cases where integer prefix is not 13,{GUID} and 14,{GUID} - find yours and remove the greater integer entry.

[image: BitLocker Recovery Tab Removal Process]

**Remove *Duplicate* Action > Find BitLocker recovery password Menu Option**

1. Keep ADSI Edit open.
2. Drill down to **Configuration** > **DisplaySpecifiers** > **409** and open up the **domainDNS-Display** container.

   - *Substitute 409 for other hex code for other (than English) locales.*
3. In the *Attribute Editor* tab, open **adminContextMenu**, select **4,{2FB1B669-59EA-4F64-B728-05309F2C11C8}**, and click Remove.

   - Note that two {2FB1B669-59EA-4F64-B728-05309F2C11C8} entries exist in this attribute. We are removing one of them. In cases where integer prefix is not 3,{GUID} and 4,{GUID} - find yours and remove the greater integer entry.

[image: Find BitLocker recovery password Removal Process]

**After completing the removals wait for Active Directory replication to complete and open/re-open ADUC on a replicated domain controller.** The changes only need to be made once per forest since changes are in the Configuration NC.

***Additional Reference***

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928202/how-to-use-the-bitlocker-recovery-password-viewer-for-active-directory